# How do I call a specific Method from a Python Script in C#?

Tags: c#, python, methods, arguments, ironpython

I'm wondering if there is a possibility to call a specific Method from a Python script over a C# project.

I have no code... but my idea is:

Python Code:

```
def SetHostInfos(Host,IP,Password):
   Work to do...

def CalcAdd(Numb1,Numb2):
   Work to do...
```

C# Code:

```
SetHostInfos("test","0.0.0.0","PWD")
result = CalcAdd(12,13)
```

How can I call one of the Methods, from this Python script, over C#?

Comment: Have you had a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7053172/how-can-i-call-ironpython-code-from-a-c-sharp-app ?

Comment: I want to pass Arguments to a Python Method and get the return value... That's what I'm trying to do.. and none of those helped me out..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I call (Iron)Python code from a C# app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7053172/how-can-i-call-ironpython-code-from-a-c-sharp-app)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can host IronPython, execute the script and access the functions defined within the script through the created scope.

The following sample shows the basic concept and two ways of using the function from C#.

```
var pySrc =
@"def CalcAdd(Numb1, Numb2):
    return Numb1 + Numb2";

// host python and execute script
var engine = IronPython.Hosting.Python.CreateEngine();
var scope = engine.CreateScope();
engine.Execute(pySrc, scope);

// get function and dynamically invoke
var calcAdd = scope.GetVariable("CalcAdd");
var result = calcAdd(34, 8); // returns 42 (Int32)

// get function with a strongly typed signature
var calcAddTyped = scope.GetVariable<Func<decimal, decimal, decimal>>("CalcAdd");
var resultTyped = calcAddTyped(5, 7); // returns 12m
```

Answer (score 6):

I found a similar way to do it, the call of the method is much easier with it.

C# Code goes as follows:

```
IDictionary<string, object> options = new Dictionary<string, object>();
options["Arguments"] = new [] {"C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\Lib", "bar"};

var ipy = Python.CreateRuntime(options);
dynamic Python_File = ipy.UseFile("test.py");

Python_File.MethodCall("test");
```

So basically I submit the Dictionary with the Library path which I want to define in my python file.

So the PYthon Script looks as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
path = sys.argv[0]  #1 argument given is a string for the path
sys.path.append(path)
import httplib
import urllib
import string

def MethodCall(OutputString):
    print Outputstring
```

So The method call is now much easier from C#
And the argument passing stays the same.
Also with this code you are able to get a custom library folder
for the Python file which is very nice if you work in a network
with a lot of different PC's

Answer (score 2):

You could make your python program take arguments on the command line then call it as a command line app from your C# code.

If that's the way to go then there are plenty of resources:

[How do I run a Python script from C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11779143/run-a-python-script-from-c-sharp)
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/charlie/archive/2009/10/25/hosting-ironpython-in-a-c-4-0-program.aspx