# How create DLL file in python?

Tags: python

I want created python file as dll file .I already created exe file using `py2exe` package . but i want dll file. How can I convert python file into dll file?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve in creating a dll?

Comment: I searched google .but i cant get any idea about convert dll file. some people refer py2exe .but i can get only exe file

Comment: Yes, but why do you need a dll? Do you need to distribute a library? Are you simply trying to include Python code in a C/C++ application? I don't believe creating a dll from Python code is a trivial task. There may be a better alternative depending on what you need to do.

Comment: yes i need to implement my python file in c#,c,C++ language

Comment: Consider [embedding the Python interpreter](https://docs.python.org/2/extending/embedding.html) in your program. Depending on what you need to do, it may be as simple as a call to `PyRun_SimpleString()`.

Comment: have a look here [How to compile a Python package to a dll](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10859369/2601521)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to compile a Python package to a dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10859369/how-to-compile-a-python-package-to-a-dll)

Answer (score -5):

Just use "open" command!

```
a = open("file.dll", "w")
a.write("something")
a.close()
```

Comment: Whilst this will create a file with the dll extension, it will not create a valid dynamic link library... the asker seems to want to create a library from their python code that can be linked to.