# compile python script for matlab use

Tags: python, matlab

I would like to know if I am going in the right direction.

I wrote a script in python and was able to run it through Matlab.
Now I would like to make it available for potential other Matlab users who do not have python installed.
I wanted to make sure that I can do such a thing by compiling my python file.

Also, the compilation in python does not seem straightforward (for example, making a dll [How to compile a Python package to a dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10859369/how-to-compile-a-python-package-to-a-dll) extending python with C) and potentially, there are some other solutions to my problem that I would be happy to investigate.

thank you for your help

*ps : if it matters, my python script is using TensorFlow, sklearn, numpy, scipy, pandas*

Comment: Maybe you want a Python "frozen binary" – a program that packages up both your Python code and the Python interpreter itself into a single executable. https://docs.python-guide.org/shipping/freezing/ Maybe there are tools that can build frozen binaries as DLLs.