# How can I run a DLL in a compiled (Pyinstaller/Py2exe) python executable (in the script itself)

Tags: python, dll, pyinstaller, py2exe, portable-executable

First, I'd like to say that I'm using this methods for evasion and research purposes, and not as best practice to achieve said functionality

I want to create a python script which will load a DLL that will be added to its executable form's resources section after using py2exe / PyInstaller.

The question is how do I reference that DLL in the script? how do i get the script to load it when essentially I still don't have a reference to it since the script wasn't compiled yet and the PE wrapper wasn't formed.

Probably just a lack of understanding on my part, just hoping for some clarity

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I use a DLL file from Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252417/how-can-i-use-a-dll-file-from-python)

Comment: No, as my goal is to load a static DLL that'll be present in the finale executable after compilation.

Comment: Okay how about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10859369/how-to-compile-a-python-package-to-a-dll)?