# Python program to windows .dll

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, dll

I am trying to convert python code in to .dll for windows.
I have tried pyinstaller but it gives directly the .exe whereas i would need .dll.
Is there any method by which i can convert the python script to .dll (not .pyd) ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10859369/how-to-compile-a-python-package-to-a-dll

Comment: Thanks Sembei. But i need .dll not .pyd