To collaborate with programmers with some parts of the code invisible but executable to collaborators
Suppose a code consists of several parts/functions. How to manage a code and collaborate with programmers with some parts of the code invisible but executable to collaborators?  To be more specific let's take Matlab, Python as examples.
Absolutely no clue. I expect that I can be informed of how to manage the code, the structure to realize my goal.

If I understood correctly you want to have a code that you share with collaborators with some parts that you want to keep secret ?
One way to do so would be to encapsulate what you consider sensitive code and call these methods through a library or such.
In language such as C and its derivatives, only the prototype would be visible in the header file while the code behind is not accessible.

right thx a lot, could you pls give an example code

I'm not a python programmer so I can't give you an example, but I found this discussion on generating a dll file from python : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10859369/how-to-compile-a-python-package-to-a-dll
and this to use a dll in a python code : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252417/how-can-i-use-a-dll-file-from-python
tell me if there is something off I will try on my side if so
