# Java and C: How can I compile this C source file into a DLL for use with Java?

Tags: java, c, dll

I bought the book Pro Android Games (even though I'm not a pro, but I'm catching up) and need to compile a DLL for use in a Java project. Here is the code:

lib.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <jni.h>

#include "include/jni_Natives.h"

#define CB_CLASS "jni/Natives"

/**
 * OnMessage callback
 */
#define CB_CLASS_MSG_CB  "OnMessage"
#define CB_CLASS_MSG_SIG  "(Ljava/lang/String;I)V"

// prototypes

// Lib main Sub
int lib_main(int argc, char **argv) ;

// Used to get the len of a Java Array
const int getArrayLen(JNIEnv * env, jobjectArray jarray);

// printf str messages back to java
void jni_printf(char *format, ...);

// Global env ref (for callbacks)
static JavaVM *g_VM;

// Global Reference to the native Java class jni.Natives.java
static jclass jNativesCls;


/*
 * Class:     jni_Natives
 * Method:    LibMain
 * Signature: ([Ljava/lang/String;)V
 */
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_jni_Natives_LibMain
  (JNIEnv * env, jclass class, jobjectArray jargv)
{
    // obtain a global ref to the caller jclass
    (*env)->GetJavaVM(env, &g_VM);

    // Extract char ** args from Java array
    jsize clen =  getArrayLen(env, jargv);

    char * args[(int)clen];

    int i;
    jstring jrow;
    for (i = 0; i < clen; i++)
    {
        // Get C string from Java Strin[i]
        jrow = (jstring)(*env)->GetObjectArrayElement(env, jargv, i);
        const char *row  = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, jrow, 0);

        args[i] = malloc( strlen(row) + 1);
        strcpy (args[i], row);

        // print args
        jni_printf("Main argv[%d]=%s", i, args[i]);

        // free java string jrow
        (*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(env, jrow, row);
    }

    /*
     * Load the jni.Natives class
     */
    jNativesCls = (*env)->FindClass(env, CB_CLASS);

    if ( jNativesCls == 0 ) {
        jni_printf("Unable to find class: %s", CB_CLASS);
        return -1;
    }

    // Invoke the Lib main sub. This will loop forever
    // Program args come from Java
    lib_main (clen, args);

    return 0;
}


/**
 * Send a string back to Java
 */
jmethodID mSendStr;

static void jni_send_str( const char * text, int level) {
    JNIEnv *env;

    if ( !g_VM) {
        printf("I_JNI-NOVM: %s\n", text);
        return;
    }

    (*g_VM)->AttachCurrentThread (g_VM,  &env, NULL); // (void **)

    // Load jni.Natives if missing
    if ( !jNativesCls ) {
        jNativesCls = (*env)->FindClass(env, CB_CLASS);

        if ( jNativesCls == 0 ) {
                printf("Unable to find class: %s", CB_CLASS);
                return;
        }
    }

    // Call jni.Natives.OnMessage(String, int)
    if (! mSendStr ) {
        // Get  aref to the static method: jni.Natives.OnMessage
        mSendStr = (*env)->GetStaticMethodID(env, jNativesCls
            , CB_CLASS_MSG_CB
            , CB_CLASS_MSG_SIG);
    }
    if (mSendStr) {
        // Call method
        (*env)->CallStaticVoidMethod(env, jNativesCls
                , mSendStr
                , (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, text)
            , (jint) level );
    }
    else {
        printf("Unable to find method: %s, signature: %s\n"
                , CB_CLASS_MSG_CB, CB_CLASS_MSG_SIG );
    }
}

/**
 * Printf into the java layer
 * does a varargs printf into a temp buffer
 * and calls jni_sebd_str
 */
void jni_printf(char *format, ...)
{
    va_list argptr;
    static char string[1024];

    va_start (argptr, format);
    vsprintf (string, format,argptr);
    va_end (argptr);

    jni_send_str (string, 0);
}

/**
 * Get java array length
 */
const int getArrayLen(JNIEnv * env, jobjectArray jarray)
{
    return (*env)->GetArrayLength(env, jarray);
}

/**
 * Library main sub
 */
int lib_main(int argc, char **argv)  
{
    int i;

    jni_printf("Entering LIB MAIN");

    for ( i = 0 ; i < argc ; i++ ) {
        jni_printf("Lib Main argv[%d]=%s", i, argv[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

When I try using VS or Dev-CPP to compile, **they always complain about not being able to find jni.h, even if I put it in the project's include directory**. Using quotation marks doesn't change anything. Also, the file jni.h is in the system path environment variable. There are also about 18 other errors, which there shouldn't be, since the author was able to compile it into an SO for Ubuntu...

I'd rather not go through the trouble of using a VM for a Linux distro, or dualbooting, but I might have to.

Thank you very much if anyone can help me build this as a DLL. :)

Comment: what is your compile line like? Your compiler will have option to specify the include directories. In this you need to include the folder which has jni.h- Typically <JDK_HOME directory/include>

Comment: I am using VS2010 and Dev-CPP.

Answer (score 0):

*Regarding building a DLL using MinGW, here are some very brief instructions.*

[Compile a DLL in C/C++, then call it from another program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847396/compile-a-dll-in-c-c-then-call-it-from-another-program)

*How To Call Native (DLL) Code From Java Using JNI*

This article details the process of calling native C/C++ code (in a DLL) from Java using JNI (Java Native Interface)

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/222092

Comment: Even using GCC as the poster explained I still get the jni.h not found error, along with a ton of other errors... Are there any problems with the code itself?

Comment: May be you are missing something. Try to look up again with free mind. You will surely get.

Comment: I'll try with Code::Blocks.