# How to Change android screen Resolution

Tags: android, android-layout, java-native-interface

I need to hardcode Android screen to a particular size(ex: 800*600) I can do this using a command "am display-size 800x600" But i don't know how to hardcode it. I have searches the entire Android Source Code, but i didn't get get that place. Please help me in achieving this....

Comment: possible duplicate of [Compile a DLL in C/C++, then call it from another program](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/847396/compile-a-dll-in-c-c-then-call-it-from-another-program)

Comment: @OrangeDog No a real dupe as this question seems to refer to the MSC/C++ compiler, whereas the question you linked uses gcc.

Answer (score 0):

**Using GCC:**

This link explains how to do it:
http://www.cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/dll.html

In short:

```
gcc -shared -o mydll.dll mydll.o
```

**Using CL:**

```
cl.exe /D_USRDLL /D_WINDLL <files-to-compile> <files-to-link> /link /DLL /OUT:<desired-dll-name>.dll
```